# how to send event from class1 to class2 and class3?

Tags: android

i want to send event on android like the implementation of event on .net.

for example => class1 contain timer that every 10 seconds he send event to all  other classes     ( class2 & class3 ) that the time got to his timeout.

How to do it with android ?

```
public final class Class1 {


private CountDownTimer _countDownTimer;


public void startTimer(){
    _countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 100)
    {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            doSomthig();

            // ****************************************
            //  HERE SEND EVENT THAT OUT_OF_TIME_TIMER
            // ****************************************
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    };

    _countDownTimer.start();
}
```

Comment: you can use interfaces holding timer or handler in Class 1.

Comment: add code embedded

Comment: Or maybe you can use eventbus library ?

Comment: either use interface or handler or you can use broadcast receiver for that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would insist you to go for [EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/), which is very nice concept of  publisher/subscriber pattern for loose coupling. It enables central communication to decoupled classes with just a few lines of code – simplifying the code, removing dependencies, and speeding up app development.

Also, there are very nice [features of EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/features/) which clearly indicate its use.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create a common Interface and extends all classes other then Class where you want timer class and hold a List of the other class which are implementing common listener and after some period of time loop that list and call interface method.

Example :

```
public class FirstClass {

    public static ArrayList<CommonInterface> mListOfInstances = new ArrayList();

    private CountDownTimer _countDownTimer;

    public void startTimer() {
        _countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 100) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mListOfInstances.size(); i++) {
                    mListOfInstances.get(i).updateClass();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
            }
        };
        _countDownTimer.start();
    }

}

public class SecondClass implements CommonInterface {

    public SecondClass() {
        FirstClass.mListOfInstances.add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateClass() {
    }
}

public class ThirdClass implements CommonInterface {

    public ThirdClass() {
        FirstClass.mListOfInstances.add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateClass() {
    }
}

public interface CommonInterface {
    void updateClass();
}
```

Comment: this is simple implimantation of observer => there is no observer on Android.SDK ?

Comment: what kind of observer you need ? above example except CountDownTimer will also work in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using Bus libraries ([EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)).

You could also implement it by yourself using callbacks, as such  -

```
public final class Class1 {

    interface TimerListener {
        void onOutOfTime();
    }

    public Class1() {
        listeners = new ArrayList<TimerListener>();
    }

    public void addListener(TimerListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    private CountDownTimer _countDownTimer;

    List<TimerListener> listeners;

    public void startTimer() {
        _countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 100) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                doSomthig();

                for(TimerListener listener:listeners)
                    listener.onOutOfTime();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        };

        _countDownTimer.start();
    }
}
```

Then in Class2 and Class3, implemet the interface `TimerListener` -

```
public class Class2 implements TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener{

    @Override
    public void onOutOfTime() {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Then, you can use the implementation like this -

```
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        Class2 class2 = new Class2();
        class1.addTimerListener(class2);
        class1.addTimerListener(new Class1.TimerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOutOfTime() {
                doSomething();
            }
        });
```

Comment: did your answer include anything extra that other two answers didn't have?

Comment: whats the need to create instance of Class1 and in which class he needs to create instance of Class1 and Class2 ?

Comment: Well, that completely depends on his implementation and requirements. I don't know the complete purpose of the classes, so I gave an example using new instances, as opposed to your example, of static classes (which is also fine, depeding on his needs).